# Script to delete directories but keep files

Tags: windows, batch-file, bulk

I am after a script to be able to do the following

I have about 2000 directories with files and folders inside them

I want to delete the main folder but keep everything inside the folder

So an exmaple of one folder

```
Folder A / Folder 2 / Video 1
           Image1
           Image2
```

So I want it to be able to delete the main first folder, in this case it would be 'Folder A'

```
Folder 2 / Video 1
Image1
Image2
```

Hope you can understand what I am wanting to do if not just ask!
Cheers

Extra info

From this

```
C:/folder A/Stuff
C:/folder B/Stuff
C:/folder C/Stuff
```

To this

```
C:/stuff
C:/sfuff
C:/sfuff
```

I just want this bat to be able to delete the folder and move everything from within that folder to the place I ran the .bat, I also want to be able to run the .bat on other drives D:/ E;/ F;/ many locations

Comment: your tag looks a bit confusing win, win8, bulk and bash.....

Comment: On Unix you could do this with `mv * ../` (from folder A). I don't know the Windows equivalent.

Comment: Not sure why win8 was in there anyway fixed it.

Comment: Agree with Kent. Are you looking for a Windows script or a *nix script?

Comment: I was looking for something like this http://pastebin.com/2kwZjpkF (.bat file) I use this one for making folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this structure in your disk:

```
C:\Folder A
|  | Folder 2
|  | | Video 1
|  | | | Image1
|  | | | Image2
```

... and you execute these commands:

```
cd "\Folder A"
move "Folder 2" ..
```

... then you get this result:

```
C:\Folder A
|  Folder 2
|  | Video 1
|  | | Image1
|  | | Image2
```

That is, it move "Folder 2" one level up, to the same level of "Folder A". If you want to do the same thing with all folders inside "Folder A" and then delete it, this Batch file do that:

```
@echo off
cd "\Folder A"
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /AD') do (
   move "%%a" ..
)
cd ..
rd "\Folder A"
```

Is this what you want?

**EDIT:** New version added as answer to new comments

```
@echo off
rem Eliminate all folders present at the same level of the Batch file
rem and move their contents one level up
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /AD') do (
   cd "%%a"
   for /F "delims=" %%b in ('dir /B /AD') do (
      move "%%b" ..
   )
   move *.* ..
   cd ..
   rd "%%a"
)
```

You must note that if two or more folders or files in the stuff have the same name, and they were originally placed directly below the top-level folders that are being deleted, then the program will issue an error and the folder or file will not be moved (and the top-level folder will not be deleted).

Antonio

Comment: Yea kind of like this but there are many many folders I wish do this in (about 1000) example http://pastebin.com/9iz1NreL I just want to be able to delete the first folder (and no matter where I run the .bat it will work (if this can be done)) Cheers

Comment: @xencored: Excuse me, I think I don't understand what you want. Do you want to process _several_ folders in the same way than `Folder A` above? It is very easy to do that, but in this case I need additional details: all the folders you want to process are at the same level in the tree? Please, edit your question above, insert 3 or 4 example folders in the same way I wrote they in my answer, and show us in the same way how do you want the final result.

Comment: Sorry Aacini it's hard for me to explain, Ive added some more info as you said hope this makes it clearer thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "relroot=c:\destdir"
SET "relrootd=c:\destdir"
SET "eliminate=folder a"
XCOPY /t /e "%relroot%\%eliminate%" "%relrootd%"
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /s /b /a-d "%relroot%\%eliminate%"') DO (
  SET dest=%%i
  SET dest=!dest:%relroot%\%eliminate%=%relrootd%!
  ECHO MOVE "%%i" "!dest!" >nul
)
```

This should do it - but it likely won't deal with some `poison` file/directoryname characters that have a special meaning to `CMD.EXE` like `^&!%` - regular alphamerics, symbols and spaces should be fine

`relroot` is the source, `relrootd` is the destination. They can be the same or different if you like. I used `c:\destdir` because that's the directory I use for testing batchfiles.

The `XCOPY` creates an appropriate empty tree.

The `DIR` output in `/b` basic mode `/s` including subdirectories `/a-d` excluding directorynames is processed line-by-line, the original `relroot` and directory-to-`eliminate`is replaced by the destination relroot and the **PROPOSED** `MOVE` operation displayed.

After verification, remove the `ECHO` keyword to ACTIVATE the move.

I'd check your original directory `relroot\eliminate` for emptiness before removing it - just to be on the safe side...

Comment: Hi thanks for this! when you say this is the source /c:destdir would I have to change this everytime? the folders are all over the place is the reason I ask! again thanks for this

Comment: Need more information. This procedure should move all of `Folder A`'s contents to - well, wherever you like. `relroot` simply gets set to `Folder A`'s parent. `relrootd` is the destination - can be anywhere on the same logical drive (if it's on a different drive, you'd need to `XCOPY` rather than `MOVE`) Now if there were many `Folder A`s, that's another question. It's relatively easy to implement BUT if your destination  is `Folder A`'s parent, then how would any routine distinguish an 'already moved' structure from a 'now move me' structure on subsequent runs?

Comment: Thanks peter, I think I am just used to using the other bat I have, I would paste the .bat to the place where I want the folders making and just open it, Anyway I have quite alot of folders in alot of random places on many harddrives I was after using this .bat on. I would like to be able to do this also (if it can be done?) Many thanks again Peter.